# Coloring of ordered and unordered lists and adjusting height

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress. I am setting some css changes in the additional css field. Since I don't know much about css, I paste the css code directly into the field. How can I color the lists and increase the height between them such as on [this website](https://www.consumernotice.org/products/child-safety)?
[Reference Site](https://www.consumernotice.org/products/child-safety)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Rcs.png)

```
 li::before {
       top: .6rem; 
       background-color: #272284;
    }
```

I added this code to the additional css field, but there was no change. This is the theme I use. On this page you can see ordered and unordered lists.
[Theme](https://demo.mekshq.com/voice/?page_id=328)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
   background-color: #ff0000
}

li {
   margin-top: 6rem; 
}
```

(ol instead of ul for ordered lists)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you probably don't want to color the whole list but just the bullets. Here's a good guide for that: [Change the Bullet Color of a List Item with CSS](https://www.lockedownseo.com/change-the-bullet-color-of-a-list-item-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the content property. Also, this creates the colored dots, so you need to turn off the list style and make each list relative so pseudo elements can position based on them:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}


li:before {
    background-color: red;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 100%;
    left: -1rem;
    top: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: The content property is the same as on this site. https://demo.mekshq.com/voice/?page_id=328